# Retrieving MySQL data as an object

Tags: java, mysql

I don't have any code right now, but was sitting around thinking of how I would code something that wishes to retrieve various data from the same row in MySQL multiple times. I was wondering if there's a line of code that allows me (in Java) to set an object equal to the retrieved results such as ...

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
tempObject = rs;
```

And then I can use a getter method that returns the various properties of that object. I'll of course close the resultset and prepared statement. I just want something that holds its values temporarily as some sort of information storage.

Comment: You can fetch the values from result set and create an object of a class that has the required class members.

Comment: And I don't get why I got a downvote. People on here are so stand-upish sometimes.

Comment: Are you aware of the [Java Persistence Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html) aka JPA?

Comment: what kind of data you want to store in your tempObject? Some specific values or any data that you are going to extract from database?

Comment: @SteveC jpa can be an overkill form small applications

Comment: @ShadowRay if you know that you will be executing in an application server then it is there for free. In that respect this question is really too broad.

Comment: @SteveC I agree , my point is that using an ORM or not using it  is always a choice not a must.

Comment: @ShadowRay Indeed. That's why I did not pose it as an answer

Comment: Hey, my bad! I was going to extract some ints and string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mapping a row from a SQL data to a Java object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993188/mapping-a-row-from-a-sql-data-to-a-java-object)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the design pattern Builder and build an Object (your model) from the resultSet by applying `getString` or `getInt` ... to populate your model attributes

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding you have two choices

First one is, Using Hibernate

```
public User getUserDetails(String userName,String passWord)
    {
        SessionFactory sf=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session=sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();


        User user=null;
        try{

            user=(User)session.createQuery("from User where userName='"+userName+"' and passWord='"+passWord+"'").list().get(0);



          }catch(Exception e)
          {

           return null; 
          }
        session.close();
        return user;
    }
```

NB:-Hibernate configuration needed, And may overkill for small projects.

Second is,

```
public Debit getAllDebits()
    {

        try{

            PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(" select * from table_debit");
           ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

           Debit debit=null;

           while(rs.next())
           {
              debit=new Debit();
              debit.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
              debit.setAmount(rs.getDouble("amount"));
              //bla
              //bla               
            }



        }catch(Exception e)
        {
             System.out.println("error in getAllDebits---------"+e);
        }
        return debit;
    }
```

NB:-Create a JDBC connection and Bean Class

Comment: You should use `Debit debit= new Debit();` instead of `Debit debit=null;` else you will get `NPE`